# Quebra de trecho específico em arquivo JSON com python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

É possível efetuar uma quebra de linha de um trecho específico do JSon, transformar em um array e depois dinamizar? Por que pergunto isso.. estou desenvolvendo um bot de mineração de arquivos e me deparei com uma situação, onde algumas páginas retornam apenas um arquivo nessa linha e outras páginas do mesmo site podem conter múltiplas informações, para que meu request seja válido e eu consiga extrair o pdf, necessito efetuar essa divisão quando houver esse caso.

Retorno no Json:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Multiplos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho do código:
Url testada: http://www.bcb.gov.br/pre/normativos/busca/normativo.asp?tipo=Circ&ano=2009&numero=003467

```
def parseHTML_JS(self, response):
    idBuscaAnexo = json.loads(response.body)['d']['results'][0]['ID']
    contente = json.loads(response.body)['d']['results'][0]['Texto']
    data = json.loads(response.body)['d']['results'][0]['Data1']
    categorias = response.meta['Categoria']
    descricao = response.meta['Description']
    titulo = response.meta['Titulo']
    pdfs = json.loads(response.body)['d']['results'][0]['DocumentosAnexados'][0:][:-5]
    url_pdfs = "http://www.bcb.gov.br/pre/normativos/busca/downloadNormativo.asp?arquivo=/Lists/Normativos/Attachments/"+str(idBuscaAnexo)+"/"+str(pdfs)
    req = Request(url=url_pdfs, callback=self.parsePdf)
    req.meta['Categoria'] = categorias
    req.meta['Description'] = descricao
    req.meta['Titulo'] = titulo
    req.meta['Content'] = contente
    req.meta['Data'] = data
    yield req
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que precisa fazer. No segundo caso, que chegam mais de um arquivo, você deseja retornar o nome de todos eles ou apenas um?

Comment: preciso retornar o seguinte retorno, por exempo:  posição 0: u'Circ_3467_v1_O.pdf', posição 1: u'Circ_3467_v2_L.pdf', posição 2: u'Circ_3467_v2_P.pdf'

Comment: consegui fazer um retorno que me traz um array, porem ainda contem o "trash" que seriam aqueles numeros junto da #, consigo isolar a # , o ; mas não sei como tirar os números

Comment: se tiver onde eu possa mostrar o código inteiro, me diga que eu te mostro o código todo

Comment: Tem a própria pergunta, é só [edit] e adicionar o código.

Comment: o StackOverflow não aceita códigos muito grandes

Comment: Então elabore um [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na string result use `result = result.split('Circ_')[1]`, isso vai eliminar o início, depois de `result = result.split('_')[0]` , isso vai pegar o número. na primeira parte voCê usa como separador o "Circ_", e com isso pega a segunda parte . Que vai estar na forma "Número_VOutroNumero_Caracter". Armazene essa segunda parte e agora dê um split na primeira metade, utilizando underline como separador, com isso vc pega o número que está na primeira parte.